# How to populate unknown Cucumber or Specflow step argument that only be generated during execution?

Tags: cucumber, specflow

Given I executed some steps, then on certain step I get a value from a database cell. Since this value is unknown prior to execution, I cannot use any binding or table value defined in feature file, is there any way to populate this value into Step Definition => then it is showed on other report?

For ex a feature file:

1. Given I drop the file to the server's UNC path
2. When the file is processed successfully
3. Then a new account is loaded as (.*) (this is the number generated at runtime)

The account can only be know at the last step through a connection to the database, is there any way to put it to the step definition so that later it shows as:

The a new account is loaded as 100051359

Comment: What does "loaded" mean in step 3? What does it mean for an account to be "loaded?" Are you just looking for the existence of an account?

Comment: @GregBurghardt ah yes, "loaded" means, within the method definition, I will make a connection manully to ensure an account is created in the database. 

But the other person said if I could include that value into the step later, then into extent report...


It is like this
@Then["A new account is loaded as (.*)"]
{
Assert.That(account, connection.IsAccountCreated());
}

Comment: So you need a way to get the account from the database to know if the account was loaded. I feel like this is doable to satisfy the test, but not in the way you want. You can't dynamically generate part of a step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible with SpecFlow. However, you can still get a good test out of this, but you will likely need to share data between steps using the ScenarioContext.

The step that processes the file will need to know the newly loaded account Id. Then that step can put that account Id in the ScenarioContext:

```cs
[Binding]
public class FileSteps
{
    private readonly ScenarioContext scenario;

    public FileSteps(ScenarioContext scenario)
    {
        this.scenario = scenario;
    }

    [When(@"the file is processed successfully"]
    public void WhenTheFileIsProcessedSuccessfully()
    {
        var account = // process the file

        scenario.Set(account.Id, "AccountId");
    }
}
```

Later when making the assertion, get the account Id from the scenario context before making your assertion:

```cs
[Binding]
public class AccountSteps
{
    private readonly ScenarioContext scenario;

    public AccountSteps(ScenarioContext scenario)
    {
        this.scenario = scenario;
    }

    [Then(@"a new account is loaded")]
    public void ThenANewAccountIsLoaded()
    {
        var account = accountRepository.Find(scenario.Get<int>("AccountId"));

        // Assert something about the account
    }
}
```

And your test becomes:

```
Scenario: ...
    Given I drop the file to the server's UNC path
    When the file is processed successfully
    Then a new account is loaded
```

Comment: Thanks, it is the way i am doing it now. Also I may have an issue when taking advantage of ObjectContainer, i may post another question later.